# Pod Install crashes when building for iOS or macOS

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, cocoa

I want to create a cross-plattform App with Flutter and Firebase. I want the App to run on iOS, Android, macOS and as a Web App.

**This is my Problem:**
When I try to run the Flutter App in the Web everything works fine, but when I try to run it as a macOS App or as an iOS App on a Simulator `pod install` crashes. These are the logs from the crash: [pod install crash log](https://pastebin.com/Rw09iuYD).
I already tried to do `pod repo update`, but that crashes with basically the same log: [pod repo update crash log](https://pastebin.com/nnARC9bM).

This is the Podfile Flutter generated:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an issue in the installed ffi..

First try doing pod install by

```dart
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

if it fails then re-install ffi using this command

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
```

then try

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Then try to build again

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But I've got some questions about that. I've looked what `arch` does,  but is it possible to tell my IDE (Android Studio), that it should also use x86_84 when doing  `pod install`?

Comment: That's probably because Ruby is now included in Mac for compatibility with legacy software. So to run the legacy way we either need to disable rosetta or use -x86_64 arch. I am not sure if we can add -x86_84 support.